# .Net Core: How to combine multiple filter expressions into a single one

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression

I have a base filter class which is responsible for checking whether a collection of entities matches the filter conditions defined in its child classes as:

```
public abstract class FilterInputBase<TEntity> : IFilterInput<TEntity>
{
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> MatchesFilter()
    {
        var input = Expression.Variable(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
        
        var expressions = GetFilterExpressions().ToList();
        if(expressions.Count == 0)
            expressions.Add(e => true);
        
        // checks if the input satisfies all the filter conditions
        var resultExpression = expressions.Aggregate(
            (l, r) => Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Invoke(l, input), Expression.Invoke(r, input)), input));
        
        return resultExpression;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of filter conditions converted into Expressions
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> GetFilterExpressions();
}
```

This class is used as:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Filter<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, IFilterInput<TEntity> filterInput) => 
        query.Where(filterInput?.MatchesFilter() ?? (x => true));
```

As the name suggests, `GetFilterExpressions` method returns a collection of filter expressions based on filter parameters. These filter conditions are aggregated in `MatchesFilter` method to form a single filter expression: `resultExpression`.

This solution was working well with up to two filter expressions. Now I need to have more than two expressions. But with more expressions, the query fails on second attempt onward. It works for the first run. I am getting the following error with more expressions added:

```
"message": "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: entity",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareLambda(LambdaExpression a, LambdaExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareInvocation(InvocationExpression a, InvocationExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareBinary(BinaryExpression a, BinaryExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareLambda(LambdaExpression a, LambdaExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareUnary(UnaryExpression a, UnaryExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareExpressionList(IReadOnlyList`1 a, IReadOnlyList`1 b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareMethodCall(MethodCallExpression a, MethodCallExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareExpressionList(IReadOnlyList`1 a, IReadOnlyList`1 b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareMethodCall(MethodCallExpression a, MethodCallExpression b)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.Equals(Expression x, Expression y)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.CompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.CompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(CompiledQueryCacheKey other)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKey other)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKey other)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(Object obj)\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValueInternal(TKey key, Int32 hashcode, TValue& value)\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& result)\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.TryGetValue[TItem](IMemoryCache cache, Object key, TItem& value)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.QueryableOffsetPagingHandler`1.ExecuteQueryableAsync(IQueryable`1 queryable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.QueryableOffsetPagingHandler`1.ResolveAsync(IResolverContext context, IQueryable`1 queryable, OffsetPagingArguments arguments)\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.OffsetPagingHandler.HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.IPagingHandler.SliceAsync(IResolverContext context, Object source)\n   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.PagingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context)\n   at HotChocolate.Utilities.MiddlewareCompiler`1.ExpressionHelper.AwaitTaskHelper(Task task)\n   at HotChocolate.Data.ToListMiddleware`1.InvokeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context)\n   at HotChocolate.Types.EntityFrameworkObjectFieldDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_1`1.<<UseDbContext>b__4>d.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at HotChocolate.Types.EntityFrameworkObjectFieldDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_1`1.<<UseDbContext>b__4>d.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeMiddleware.InvokeAsync(IDirectiveContext context)\n   at HotChocolate.Utilities.MiddlewareCompiler`1.ExpressionHelper.AwaitTaskHelper(Task task)\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

I believe `expressions.Aggregate()` isn't probably to right way to do it. Is there a better way to approach this? Also, do I need to clear any cached dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into a similar issue, here is the solution I figured out that actually worked for me.

```
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> MatchesFilter()
    {
        var expressions = GetFilterExpressions().ToList();

        if (expressions.Count <= 1)
            return expressions.FirstOrDefault() ??  (x => true);

        var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        
        var resultExpression = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Invoke(expressions[0], input), Expression.Invoke(expressions[1], input));
        resultExpression = expressions.Skip(2).Aggregate(resultExpression, (current, expression) =>
            Expression.AndAlso(current, Expression.Invoke(expression, input)));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(resultExpression, input);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is recursively create BinaryExpressions and just wrap them around with more BinaryExpressions

For example you have the following:

```
x => x > 1 
x => x == 2
x => x < 3
x => x != 4
```

We basically take the last two expressions and create a binary expression out of it

```
   var lastExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso,
                        expression3, expression4);
```

Then you add the 2nd one and the first one

```
   lastExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, 
                    expression2, lastExpression);

   lastExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, 
                    expression1, lastExpression);
```

This way you will create something like the following expression:

```
x => (x > 1 && (x == 2 && (x < 3 && x != 4)))
```

Which you just need to invoke

```
Expression.invoke(lastExpression, input);
```

Comment: thanks. I tried your approach and updated my aggregation code to 

`var resultExpression = expressions.Aggregate((l,r) => Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                 Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, l, r), input));`

But Now I am getting the following error:
The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[GraphQL.Api.Data.Models.User,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func`2[GraphQL.Api.Data.Models.User,System.Boolean]'.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, no I didn't write the code you need to do. You have to remove .Aggregate and recursively build the binary expression. I only did a layout of the idea and not the whole code because its too much work

Comment: Sorry, still got the same error with what you suggested, however, I figured out the solution to it inspired by yours. Thanks.